# Can I disable ViewCell.ContextActions based on a condition

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I using a Xamarin Forms ListView and I want to know if I can disable the Context Actions based on a certain binding or in the code behind.

I am using one GroupedListView for the whole application but it displays different data based on what the user is doing. There is a "Manage your Favorites" feature where I want the user to be able to swipe-to-delete on iOS or long-press on android to remove a ListItem, but I do not want this behavior if the list is displaying some search result or something else

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ListViewPage}}"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

This did not disable it...

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions IsEnabled="false"> //This IsEnabled does nothing
    <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ListViewPage}}"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

How can I disable the ContextActions? I dont wan't the user to always be able to swipe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For what I wanted to achieve I did the following...

In the XAML

```
<ViewCell BindingContextChanged="OnBindingContextChanged">
```

In the code behind

```
private void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBindingContextChanged();

    if (BindingContext == null)
        return;

    ViewCell theViewCell = ((ViewCell)sender);
    var item = theViewCell.BindingContext as ListItemModel;
    theViewCell.ContextActions.Clear();

    if (item != null)
    {
        if (item.ListItemType == ListItemTypeEnum.FavoritePlaces
           || item.ListItemType == ListItemTypeEnum.FavoritePeople)
        {
            theViewCell.ContextActions.Add(new MenuItem()
            {
                Text = "Delete"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Based which type of list item we are dealing with, we get to decide where to place the context actions

Comment: Don't call `base.OnBindingContextChanged`. That's for the page's binding context. This is an event handler, not a virtual method override.

Comment: I was young and reckless. It was a different time in my life

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways to go about this.

1. You can remove the `MenuItem` form the `ContextActions` based on your conditions. This cannot be done by pure XAML, you're going to have to do some code-behind.
2. Another option is to look at the [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/). This lets you select a template for your ViewCell (or Cells) at runtime. In that template you can choose to add the `ContextActions` or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I looked into the DataTemplateSelector and it looks like a good solution to my problem. I found another way to do this by using 'BindingContextChanged' on the ViewCell

Comment: @GeraldVersluis can i help with  please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370263/how-delete-an-menu-item

Answer (score -3):

Simply disabling the cell works, but for Android only not iOS. Tested with a Xamarin Forms (2.0.5782) project on both iOS and Android.

```
<ViewCell IsEnabled="false">
```

Notice it is on the ViewCell and not the ViewCell.ContextActions like you have in your sample.

Comment: But you can not just disabled it as there is a condition to check

Comment: Xamarin Forms 3.6.x throws an exception if you try to set or bind IsEnabled