# hide view cell context actions menu item based on list view Item (xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I am using a listview. Based on the listview item the data templates are selected. In View cell, I have defined some view cell context actions. based on items context actions need to change dynamically.
here is my list view:

```
<ListView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" IsRefreshing="{Binding PullToRefreshEnable}" RefreshCommand="{Binding PullToRefreshCommand}" 
                                  IsGroupingEnabled="True" x:Name="UserMessagesListView" ItemSelected="UserMessagesListView_ItemSelected" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Frame HasShadow="True" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="4" Padding="3" CornerRadius="22" BackgroundColor="#d4eaf4">
                                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10,5">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding MessageRecieveDate}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="11" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

My listview datatemplate selector:

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public MyDataTemplateSelector()
    {
        // Retain instances!
        this.incomingDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(IncomingMessageViewCell));
        this.outgoingDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(OutgoingMessageViewCell));
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var messageVm = item as ChatModel;
        if (messageVm == null)
            return null;
        return messageVm.IsIncoming ? this.incomingDataTemplate : this.outgoingDataTemplate;
    }

    private readonly DataTemplate incomingDataTemplate;
    private readonly DataTemplate outgoingDataTemplate;
}
```

Below are there are code samples for IncomingMessageViewCell and OutGoingMessageViewCell

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         x:Class="BTrak.Chat.Controls.OutgoingMessageViewCell">
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem IconImageSource="EditMessage.png" Clicked="EditMenuItem_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    <MenuItem IconImageSource="DeleteMessage.png" Clicked="DeleteMenuItem_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    <MenuItem IconImageSource="CopyText.png" Clicked="CopyMenuItem_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
//Design
```

Incoming view cell:

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="BTrak.Chat.Controls.IncomingMessageViewCell">
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem IconImageSource="CopyText.png" Clicked="CopyMenuItem_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
//design
```

how to hide menu items base on the item selected and context actions are not switching from once we long press on incoming view cell and later on outgoing view cell vise verse 
Anyone help me how to hide the menu item of view cell context actions and how to elevate other view cell context actions on holding that item.

Comment: Looks a lot like this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581927/how-to-add-visibility-binding-for-menuitem-of-contextactions-of-a-listview

Comment: Is there a way to inherit menu item class and create a bindable property

Comment: You can try to add/remove context actions based on the item type in the ViewCell.You can refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104352/can-i-disable-viewcell-contextactions-based-on-a-condition/38149080

Comment: thanks, @JessieZhang-MSFT that works for me to handle menu items, But I am still facing issue context actions not changing based on selected item

Comment: My issue is resolved after updating xamarin forms [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/viewcell-context-actions)

Comment: Congrats.Happy coding... :)